# How did AAVE dapp calculate the “maximum available withdraw” value (v2)?

Tags: erc-20, tokens, defi, aave

I can not find the dapp of aave manage to find the exact amount that I can withdraw.

I have 5 "aUSDC" but when I go on dapp, I can only withdraw 4.3.
I know it's due to the debt of another token because when I tried on a wallet wihout debt it worked (full amount) but I can't find how this value is calculated.

When I call "getUserReserveData" on the data provider protocol (0x057835Ad21a177dbdd3090bB1CAE03EaCF78Fc6d  I get my exact balance but not the amount I can withdraw.
I also saw that if I call "getUserAccountData" on the lending pool provider (0x7d2768de32b0b80b7a3454c06bdac94a69ddc7a9), I get totalCollateralETH , totalDebtETH and availableBorrowsETH but I still can't calculate the amount of token I can withdraw.

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: Is there sufficient liquidity in Aave to obtain aUSDC? Could you provide more details about the network you tested it on?